# Atmosphere and REST call

Tags: jersey, cxf, atmosphere

I'm using the Atmosphere framework to develop a notification service.
I would like to know if there's a way to replace the Jersey component by the Apache CXF framework.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Show us what have you done so far.

Comment: Hi ! Sorry for this looong delay. I have low level Atmosphere problem, so the integration of CXF with Atmosphere will no be done before I resolve the primary problem :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no native module for CXF but it should be pretty easy use Atmosphere API in CFX. Let's have the discussion on atmosphere-framework@googlegroups.com (details).

Comment: Could you please post your results here as an answer, in case other people are looking for the same info?

Comment: Looking forward to seeing the results